# Getting error in calculation of mean for tiff file by using calc function

Tags: raster, r

I have a 4 raster tiff files and I want to calculate the mean of it. I am using the "calc" funtion for it. My code is following .

```
    library(raster)
    fs <- list.files(path="directory", pattern = "tif$", full.names = TRUE)
    s <- raster::stack(fs)
    s1 <- calc(s, mean)
```

**Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an inherited method for function ‘calc’ for signature ‘"RasterStack", "RasterLayer"**

It give me this error but If I use sd (standard deviation)instead of mean it give me result but not working for mean.

I don't know what's going on with mean calculation.

Could anybody explain it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the error message:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited 
method for function ‘calc’ for signature ‘"RasterStack", "RasterLayer"
```

the "signature" is telling me the first argument is a RasterStack but the second argument is a RasterLayer. That means "mean" is a RasterLayer. Do you have a RasterLayer called "mean"? That would be overriding the "mean" function. I can replicate your error this way. First it works:

```
> m = matrix(1:12,3,4)
> r = raster(m)
> s = stack(list(r,r,r))
> mm = calc(s, mean)
>
```

Then I make a raster called "mean":

```
> mean = r
> mm = calc(s, mean)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘calc’ for signature ‘"RasterStack", "RasterLayer"’
```

Fix either by removing the "mean" raster, or using `base::mean` to get the right mean function:

```
> mm = calc(s, base::mean)
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply.  The thing is what I felt after your comment is these 4 tiff files are actually stack of multiple files. I took the mean and made these 4 files from 5-5 separate files after taking their mean. Secondly, files name has no 'mean' word in it _Spacedman.

Comment: I don't understand. Does your code work with your data if you use `base::mean` instead of just `mean`? If so then you've got an object called "mean" in your search path that is breaking `calc`.

Comment: @user_3264 it doesn't matter that there's no "mean" in the 4 files you read in. There's an object called "mean" somewhere that is getting used instead of R's "mean" function. Maybe you created it yesterday, or a week ago, or its been reloaded from R's saved .RData. But it must be there. If I'm right please accept the answer.

Comment: Yes thank you so much for detailed guidance again.  I accept the answer.